# Awk sum columns from 2 different matching fields

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I have a dataset with 2 different row identifiers, I would like to get the ratio between 2 separate columns using the 2 different row identifiers and output into a separate file.

For example:

*Input*

```
 Avpr1a CG  1 30
 Avpr1a CHG 2 15
 Avpr1a CHH 1 15
 Avpr1a CG  2 25
 Avpr1a CHG 5 15
 Avpr1a CHH 8 15
 BDNF   CG  1 15
 BDNF   CHG 2 15
 BDNF   CHH 3 10
 BDNF   CG  8 20
```

What i want is based on column $1,$2 ,get the ratio of sum of $3/sum of $4 to obtain the following (for ex. AVPR1a CG 3/55 = 0.05)

*Output*

```
 Avpr1a CG  0.05
 Avpr1a CHG 0.233
 Avpr1a CHH 0.3
 BDNF   CG  0.xxx
 BDNF   CHG 0.xxx
 BDNF   CHH 0.xx
```

You get the idea.

I am currently doing it really stupidly by separately summing the columns, merge and divide

```
awk '{a[$1,$2]+=$3}END{for(i in a){print i, a[i]}}'
awk '{a[$1,$2]+=$4}END{for(i in a){print i, a[i]}}'
merge
awk and print $3/$4 from intermediate files
```

Is it possible to achieve what I want to do in a single awk command?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is even fairly easy:

```
awk '{s1[$1,$2] = $1; s2[$1,$2] = $2; s3[$1,$2] += $3; s4[$1,$2] += $4}
     END { for (i in s3) print s1[i], s2[i], s3[i]/s4[i] }' data
```

Output:

```
Avpr1a CG 0.0545455
BDNF CHG 0.133333
BDNF CHH 0.3
Avpr1a CHG 0.233333
BDNF CG 0.257143
Avpr1a CHH 0.3
```

If you don't capture the separate items in `s1` and `s2` but print `i` instead, you get output with the `\034` character separating the two name files.  You can fix that, with `tr` for example, but it is simpler not to need to do so.

Comment: Don't worry; it comes with practice.  It's easier after 30 years of using `awk`.